# jQuery - Make a table with fixed header sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tablesorter

I have an HTML table on [this site](http://codepen.io/jgx/pen/wiIGc)

The header of the table is fixed with JavaScript. Now I also want the possibility to sort each column. Therefore I used jQuery's [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin. The problem is that the JavaScript on codepen.io copys the header of the table. In the DOM there are now two table headers. `TableSorter` accesses the first table, which was copied, but this table has no `tbody` so the table won't be sorted by `TableSorter`.

Is there a posibility to have both (table header fixed and sorting by clicking on columns)?

Comment: You should post the relevant code here. Your problem revolves around jQuery yet there is no mention of it. I edited your post & title to make that more clear and tagged it appropriately. Additionally, next time you might want to use the link & code buttons to format your posts.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/). It inlcudes two versions of a sticky (fixed) headers widget.

- [stickyHeader widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-sticky-header.html) - uses `position: absolute` to fix the header.
- [css3 stickyHeader widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-css-sticky-header.html) - uses css3 `transform` to fix the header.

Sorry, neither of these widgets were designed to work with the original tablesorter.